# How to retrieve image from firebase storage Swift 4 ios

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, storage

I am trying to retrieve an image from firebase storage but the image that I retrieve always is `nil` for some reason.

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
var storageRef: StorageReference!
var hallData = [Hall]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let refHandle = Database.database().reference().child("hallData").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
         let values = Array(postDict.values)
        //print(values)
        let valueDict = values as! [[String:Any]]

        for i in valueDict
        {
            var name = i["name"] as! String
            var address = i["address"] as! String
            var capacity = i["capacity"] as! String
            var decorations = i["decorations"] as! String
            var highPrice = i["highPrice"] as! String
            var lowPrice = i["lowPrice"] as! String
            var catering = i["catering"] as! String
            var email = i["email"] as! String
            self.storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images").child(email)
            var image: UIImage!
            // Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)

            self.storageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in

                if let error = error {
                    print("PLASESEE")
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                } else {
                    // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                }
            }
        print(image)
            self.hallData.append(Hall(name2: name, capacity2: capacity, lowPrice2: lowPrice, highPrice2: highPrice, catering2: catering,decorations2: decorations, address2:address, image2: image, email2: email))
        }
    })
}
```

I dont understand what I am doing wrong, I followed the api on firebase storage, checked out a lot of tutorials but I keep getting `nil`

Comment: Hi, Bob. First of all, don't use capitalized words, please.

Comment: @Vyacheslav oh thank you, but do you have an answer for me pls

Comment: Are you getting an error or is the image nil for island.png?

Comment: You create an image container variable with 'var image: UIImage!'.  Instead of setting an image from getData to it, you create a new variable with the same name.  That's why you go nowhere.

Comment: @ElTomato Good catch. The other issue is where the var is being assigned - outside the closure.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're attempting to work with the *image* var *outside* the getData closure.

```
    self.storageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("PLASESEE")
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
            } else {
                // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            } <- closure ends here and image is only valid above this
        }
        print(image) <- image may not be populated at this point
        self.hallData.append... image
    }
```

That closure is asynchronous and the call to `self.hallData.append...` will occur way before the image var is populated within the closure. Code is much faster than the internet

Move that statement inside the closure, right after the `let image =` and it should work.

```
       self.storageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
           if let error = error {
               print("An error occurred in downloading the image")
               print(error.localizedDescription)
           } else {
               let image = UIImage(data: data!)
               self.hallData.append... image
               //reload your tableView or UI as self.hallData is now valid
           }
       }
```

If you do it this way, the preceeding `var image: UIImage!` can be removed as it doesn't have a function. Otherwise, remove the let before let image = within the closure.